# My Application is showing blank white canvas

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

#Problem#
Here is my code it is a simple app for practising provider package but when I run it a blank
canvas shows up.

#What I want from it#
Can anyone tell me the reason why nothing is showing up on screen? I have tried creating a fresh project and running it still didn't work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => const MyApp();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(
      create: (context) => Data(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark(),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const MyText(),
          ),
          body: const Level1(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Level1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Level1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Level2();
  }
}

class Level2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Level2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: const [
        MyTextField(),
        Level3(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Level3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Level3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(Provider.of<Data>(context).data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a tiny bug in your code... line 4

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

//void main() => const MyApp(); 
void main() => runApp(const MyApp()); // Update this line.

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  ...
```

---

In flutter land, the `runApp` function is responsible for inflating the root  widget.

Update your `main` function to call the `runApp` function and pass in the root widget, *`MyApp` in this case*. That should solve the issue.